# Bundler: read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL ::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I use windows, and I have an error when execute `bundle` or `bundle install`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.0
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [i386-mingw32]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86-mingw32
- GEM PATHS:
 - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
 - C:/Users/Usuario/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://rubygems.org/
```

Error message:

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/v
endor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 e
rrno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL
::SSL::SSLError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `block in connect'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-           1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:628:in `start'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:570:in `connection_for'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:930:in `request'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:195:in `fetch'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:169:in `use_api'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `block in remote_specs'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `select'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `remote_specs'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:162:in `fetch_specs'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/
bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I already tried `bundle install --system`, `bundle install --path path/to_the/proect`.

Answer (score 6):

This error means your certificate is nonexistent or invalid. It is a common issue.

Here's a comprehensive post on how to solve it: http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html (including how to deal with it on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround over here check thi

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Simple copy paste if certificate verification failed error